# Counting unique visitors in access log

Tags: bash, logging

I'm aware I am probably reinventing the wheel somewhat here, but I am trying to teach myself simple bash coding by completing simple tasks such as parsing files.

To that end I am looking to learn what elephants in the room I could be missing or if there are better ways to use the core functionality of bash without installing any additional tools.

This simple code returns a list of unique IP addresses that have hit the index of my site along with a count of the hits.

```
a="access.log"; for b in $(cat $a | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq);do echo $b;grep $a -e "GET / HTTP" | grep -c $b;done;
```

Assumptions:
access.log is in the current directory and is in the regular format

Any advice or suggestions for improvement are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your code is hardly a bash solution, is it? You use `sort`, `awk`, `grep`, and `echo`....

Additionally, your code is dumped on a single line, and it makes it hard to read. Why not put it in a script, and have separate commands on separate lines.... like:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="access.log"
for b in $(cat $a | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq); do
  echo $b;
  grep $a -e "GET / HTTP" | grep -c $b;
done;
```

Those variable names.... ouch. `a` and `b` make it hard to separate from the `-c` and `-e` too.... and they mean nothing otherwise. Why not use meaningful names like `ip` and `log`?

Then, when I ran the code, I got a lot of funny results.... like:

> ```
> 54.69.125.145
> 1
> 61.240.144.65
> 0
> 64.14.99.254
> 0
> 66.196.235.78
> 0
> 66.249.64.188
> 0
> 74.208.152.232
> 0
> ```

Why are there `0` counts.... oh, that's because those are IP's that are not accessing the home page, but are accessing other pages... they appear as `$b` but don't actually "GET" `/`.

I would consider making it more a study of `bash` and use the native `bash` structures to get things right.... no `grep`, `awk`, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

# use first commandline argument if supplied
log="access.log"
if [ $1 ] ; then
    log="$1"
fi

# set a variable to match in a regular expression
match="GET / HTTP"

# create a named array.
declare -A counts

# read the file line-by-line
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

  # find lines that access GET / HTTP
  if [[ $line =~ $match ]] ; then

    # get just the IP of the client
    ip=${line%% *}
    # get the previous count, default to 0
    prev=${counts[$ip]:-0}
    # increment the count for this IP
    counts[$ip]=$(($prev + 1))
  fi
done < "$log"

for ip in "${!counts[@]}" ; do
    echo "IP $ip visited ${counts[$ip]} times"
done
```

EDIT: About the `${line%% *}` variable substitution. The possibilities when doing variables in bash are remarkably powerful. I recommend looking at the document [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for details, and [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is good as well (but does not have the examples). The `%%` token indicates that there should be a pattern search backward from the end of `$line` for a space  followed by any characters (the `*` - this is a "glob" expression, not a regex). This pattern essentially looks for the first space, and removes it and any charaters after it. The man page document says:

> ```
> ${parameter%word}
> ${parameter%%word}
>
>     The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion.
>     If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of
>     parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter
>     with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching
>     pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern
>     removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>     expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>     subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to
>     each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

Comment: `{line%% *}` seems an overkill. `while read -r ip rest` (notice the absence of IFS) will conveniently split the line into `ip` and the rest.

Comment: @vpn - that's a great suggestion - and a trick I may use in the future for other things too. I have only ever used `read` to pull things in to a single variable before.

Comment: `echo` is a bash builtin, so complaining about its use is going a bit too far.  Using `sort` and `awk` within shell scripts is probably smarter than redoing those things in `bash` even if the OP seemed to be trying to do that.

Comment: +1 I actually thought sort, awk, grep were built in... so that's my first learning experience of the day straight away. Your code is far more readable and robust, I can follow what you've done apart from the line `ip=${line%% *}` can you explain that line any futher?

Comment: @DarrenH - added references for the `%%` variable expander.

Answer (score 4):

First, you're making one pass to extract all of the client IP addresses.  Then, for each address, you process *the entire file again* to obtain the hit count.  For any large log file, performance is going to suck!

There are some micro-optimizations that could be done (such as removing the superfluous use of `cat`, and combining `sort | uniq` as `sort -u`), but that won't change the fact that this is an O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) solution that should be rewritten for efficiency.

My general recommendation for line-oriented processing is to use just `awk`, because that's what it's good at.

```
awk '
    /GET \/ HTTP/ { count[$1] += 1 }
    END { for (ip in counts) { print ip, "\t", counts[ip] } }
' access.log | sort -n -r -k 2
```

This solution uses an AWK's associative array to do all of the counting in one pass.  We completely ignore all entries other than `GET / HTTP` requests.  Each IP address and its count are printed on the same line, for easier interpretation of the results.  Since, in my opinion, it doesn't do much good to sort dotted-quad IP addresses, I suggest sorting by hit count instead.

Comment: This has opened my eyes to how large `awk` really is, looks like I have a lot of reading to do. Can you suggest any easy-to-follow sources of information on this and similar commands?

Comment: [Is there a basic tutorial for grep, awk and sed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2434/17535)